# Peterson's N-Process Algorithm Query

Tags: java, c#, python, c++, algorithm

Hi guys I am just inquiring what is meant by k is this situation.

```
while (waiting[count] == id && (there exists k != i, such that level[k] >= count)) {
            // busy wait
}
```

Thanks

Comment: *Unclear what is asked*

Comment: I would imagine it means some integer (which we'll call "k") such that it is not equal to "i". Perhaps there are constraints on "k" such that it is a valid index into "level"

Answer (score 0):

In the generalized version of Petersons Algorithm, also called filter algorithm: k iterates over N (= the Number of threads). K shall not be i, which is the threads own "id", so k shall be another thread that has a highter level than the thread "i himself".

To put it in one sentence: "wait until there is no other thread with a higher level(or interest) k than me"

See here for more info: https://www.cs.rice.edu/~vs3/comp422/lecture-notes/comp422-lec19-s08-v1.pdf page 23 and 24

It could help to check out peterson's lock on the pages before since the names of the variables purposes continue.